# Finding Percentage Via Query

Tags: sql

I have a question regarding SQL.

Say I have the following table:

```
customerID | time_secs
-----------+-----------
1          | 5
1          | 4
1          | 2
2          | 1
2          | 3
3          | 6
3          | 8
```

I can't change the table design. I want to be able to calculate for each unique customer, the percent of time_secs that is over 3.

So for example, for customer 1, it would be (2 / 3) * 100 %.

I've gotten this so far:

```
SELECT customerID, COUNT(time_secs)
WHERE time_secs > 3 
GROUP BY service
```

How do I make sure the time_secs is above 3 and also divides it by the total count of time_secs regardless if it's above 3 or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is conditional aggregation:

```
select customerid,
       avg(case when time_seconds > 3 then 100.0 else 0 end) as ratio
from t
group by customerid;
```

The `avg()` is a convenient shorthand for:

```
sum(case when time_seconds > 3 then 100.0 else 0 end) / count(*)
```

Comment: Oh very interesting. Didn't know you could do that! What if I added a date column to the table? And I wanted to calculate the ratio for each date for each customer? It won't let me group by date when I'm selecting the customer and time_seconds.

Comment: @legit98 . . . Then you would have a different question and that should be asked as a new question.